# Export and import vocabulary terms via Features (uuid_features)

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

If I import taxonomy terms data exported via Features (uuid_features) the tids of terms will be the same or it will differ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the **uuid_features** module enabled, you can go to the module configuration page (*www.yourwebsite/admin/structure/features/uuid_features*) and you will see a checkbox called "**Auto detect uuid terms**".

The description of the checkbox says "**When exporting a vocabulary, include its terms**".

If you have this checked and export a taxonomy vocabulary, all of its terms will also be included in the export. If you **don't** want to include the terms when importing you can leave this checkbox unchecked.

**Edited**

If the terms on the website you are importing already have **UUIDs** the terms should be overwritten for example if you are importing term called **term1** and you already have **term1** on your website and their **UUIDs** are the same you will end up with only one **term1**.

But if the terms on the website where you are importing the terms into don't have **UUIDs**, after the import you will end up with **two** terms called **term1**.

What I would do doesn't matter which case you are up against, would be to delete all the terms within the taxonomy vocabulary you are importing into and after that do the import.

You could delete the terms from the www.yourwebsite/devel/php page, if you have the [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module enabled. Just copy/paste the following code:

```
$vocabulary = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load('my_custom_vocabulary');
foreach (taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary->vid) as $term) {
  taxonomy_term_delete($term->tid);
}
```

Comment: ok, but I am interested to have the same taxonomy terms id after import